# Android Google Play - Should I license my paid app or is it optional?

Tags: android, google-play, android-lvl

Is adding licensing to my paid app optional when using Google Play or is it required that I do it before uploading?

When I try to upload the app now it says that it is not recognized.  Should I have added licensing in before uploading?

Answer (score 3):

Optional but indispensable... See [Licensing Android](http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/index.html)

You can of course publish a paid app without licensing, but it's discouraged for your wallet !